# C# => Control in which order your properties appear in the MS PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, sorting, propertygrid

I am using the Microsoft PropertyGrid and I have 2 Categories with 6 Properties:

```
Category "B"
 "test1"
 "test2"
 "test3"
 "yoman"

Category "Z"
 "test4"
 "test5"
```

What must I do that "**yoman**" comes at **first** item in Category "**B**" ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TypeConverter attribute on the class and a Custom Attribute on each Property to Control the display order of Properties in a PropertyGrid. The classes are small and the attributes are straightforward. The code and running example are available in a Code Project article by Paul Tingey (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6611/Ordering-Items-in-the-Property-Grid).

Answer (score 1):

Showing properties in the exact order you want while still showing Categories is not easy. 
(If you would not care about seeing the categories you could just use `PropertyGrid.PropertySort=NoSort` to get your properties in the order as they appear in your code but without showing categories).

This article gives some kind of hack to specify the order while showing categories:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/PropertyGridValidation.aspx